# Finding all the objects that are pointing to a certain object? (python)

Tags: python

If I have the ID of some object for example, how can I find out all the objects that are pointing to it?

Comment: You can't, at least, not within the Python environment.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with such information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396668/python-get-object-by-id

Comment: In a linked list, I want to be able to go backwards

Comment: That's what a double linked list is for. Why are you using a linked list in Python?

Comment: I actually learned linked lists today and asked my prof if it's possible to go backwards and he said no (unless it's a double linked list), so I wanted to prove him wrong :p

Comment: get_referrers(...)
    get_referrers(*objs) -> list
    Return the list of objects that directly refer to any of objs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was the discussion in your class about linked list specifically about python, or was it a general CS discussion regarding  linked lists?

Comment: We talked about it generally and then also implemented functions in python

Answer (score 1):

```
import gc

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Node(5)
    a.next = Node(4)
    a.next.next = Node(3)
    # returns a list of dictionary of the object(s) referring to a.next.next
    diction = gc.get_referrers(a.next.next)[0]
    diction['next'] = None
    print a.next.next
```

The garbage collector has some neat functions

```
get_referrers(...)
    get_referrers(*objs) -> list
    Return the list of objects that directly refer to any of objs.

get_referents(...)
    get_referents(*objs) -> list
    Return the list of objects that are directly referred to by objs.
```

Comment: I dont consider this a way to skirt around calling it a double linked list. This is basically just relying on the gc automatically tracking references instead of storing the reference on your object. It would technically be no different if you were storing the backward references in a separate dict of your own...or then...just simply storing them on the node object itself...hence...a double linked list. Its just playing a game of where the reference is managed. You will end up writing a "go backward" method around this and probably store it on the Node anyways.

Comment: Yea, my point is that I don't think it will go over well to present this as proof of the ability to implement a linked list that can also go  backwards :-)