# How to access variable by id?

Tags: python, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get object by id()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396668/get-object-by-id)

```
>>> var = 'I need to be accessed by id!'
>>> address = id(var)
>>> print(address)
33003240
```

Is there any way to use address of `var` in memory, provided by `id()`, for accessing value of `var`?

**UPD:**
I also want to say, that if this cannot be done in standard Python, it also would be interesting, if this somehow could be implemented via hacking C++ internals of Python.

**UPD2:**
Also would be interesting to know, how to *change* value of `var`.

Comment: You can't. The return value of `id()` is not a reference. The fact that cpython returns a memory address here is a implementation detail, and using this as a reference is *not* the goal of the function.

Comment: Why on any deity's name would you want to do that? Martijn is correct, even if you could somehow hack it in CPython, it's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There are probably other ways to achieve whatever you are need done.

Comment: First goal: fun; Second: passing-by-reference - sometimes its needed for more flexibility, despite its not pythonic. Its a zen-question, no practical background.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense that to get the `id` of an object, you've had to have a reference to the name to do so... So at that point, just keep the name hanging around rather than some convoluted in-direct method of getting it back...

Comment: If it's only for fun you can create an id to object map: `{id(v):v for k,v in globals().iteritems()}`

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wanted to answer you but forgot then. Memory address is memory address - whatever programming language we use - memory address always remains what it is - address where chunk of data stored. Variable in python also have its address, but `id()` returns address of data to what points Python variable. In Python all variables are just pointers behind the scenes.

Comment: It's possible. See accepted answer to duplicate question [**_Is it possible to dereference variable id's?_**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011674/is-it-possible-to-dereference-variable-ids)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A solution, only for your case, would be:

```
var = 'I need to be accessed by id!'
address = id(var)
print(address)
var2 = [x for x in globals().values() if id(x)==address]
```

It also works from inside a function like

```
def get_by_address(address):
    return [x for x in globals().values() if id(x)==address]

var = 'I need to be accessed by id!'
address = id(var)
print(address)
var2 = get_by_address(address)
```

But as others pointed out: **First make sure there is no better solution that better fits your needs**

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1396690/514485. And like almost everyone else I caution you, you probably don't want/need to do this.