# Is it possible to dereference variable id's?

Tags: python, memory, dereference

Can you dereference a variable id retrieved from the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) function in Python? For example:

```
dereference(id(a)) == a
```

I want to know from an academic standpoint; I understand that there are more practical methods.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here's a utility function based on a (now-deleted) comment made by "Tiran" in a weblog [discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20090404012257/http://www.friday.com/bbum/2007/08/24/python-di/) @Hophat Abc references in [his own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012076/355230) that will work in both Python 2 and 3.

**Disclaimer:** If you read the the linked discussion, you'll find that some folks think this is so unsafe that it should *never* be used (as likewise mentioned in some of the comments below). I don't agree with that assessment but feel I should at least mention that there's some debate about using it.

```
import _ctypes

def di(obj_id):
    """ Inverse of id() function. """
    return _ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(obj_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 42
    b = 'answer'
    print(di(id(a)))  # -> 42
    print(di(id(b)))  # -> answer
```

Comment: But be warned that this will segfault the interpreter if you pass it an invalid address (say, because it's been garbage collected).

Comment: Segfault, or worse. For example, there might be some other object living there now, and your program will silently chug along with the wrong object and make wrong decisions as a result, deleting your files or leaking your users' data or revving up the bandsaw your program was supposed to control or worse.

Comment: FWIW, I've actually used something like this to work around some limitations of the [JSON module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249415/how-to-implement-custom-indentation-when-pretty-printing-with-the-json-module). I think there are scenarios where it's "safe enough" to consider using.

Comment: @martineau: I wouldn't consider that safe, and certainly not safe enough to post on Stack Overflow for people to copy without even realizing it's doing something unsafe. It would have been much better to traverse the input to find all the NoIndent instances instead of trying to go from ID to object by direct memory access. The use of PyObj_FromPtr is a crash risk and security issue if there's any possibility a string that looks like `@@123@@` could be in the output without coming from a `NoIndent`, and even if that can't happen to you, it could happen to anyone who uses your answer.

Comment: Or, since you have access to the `NoIndent` object in your `default` method, you could have saved a reference to it there (and then cleared the saved references in `encode` or something to avoid keeping objects alive).

Comment: @user2357112: Guess we'll just have to agree to disagree. The pattern used can be easily changed as needed and the whole saving references for later look up has its own potentially serious issues wrt keeping objects alive.

Comment: I was a little disturbed by the use of the undocumented `_ctypes` module here (which I'd never heard of), and couldn't find much on Google about why it exists, so have asked [a question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58475560/1709587). Perhaps you have wisdom to share about it; if so, I invite you to take a look.

Comment: @MarkAmery: You can also do it with `ctypes` if that's what is bothering your (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396668/get-object-by-id/15702647#15702647)).

Comment: There's a race condition here. There's no guarantee that the object with `obj_id` as its identifier still exists by the time you call `PyObj_FromPtr`. I don't know what `PyObj_FromPtr` does if you give it an invalid id, but it can also return a *different* object than the one you expect, if a new object has recycled the id.

Comment: Does this work on multiprocessing?

Comment: @somePythonProgrammer: No, processes run in separate memory-spaces so passing the id of an object in one of them to another isn't feasible. It would work OK completely *within* one of them though.

Comment: `PyObj_FromPtr` is part of the private API.
This can be done while using the official API with `ctypes.cast(some_id, ctypes.py_object).value` instead.

Comment: A lot of people here pointing out safety issues, but these apply generally to dereferencing any unknown pointer, not to questions of how python implements object ids.

Answer (score 10):

Not easily.

You could recurse through the [`gc.get_objects()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_objects) list, testing each and every object if it has the same `id()` but that's not very practical.

The `id()` function is *not intended* to be dereferenceable; the fact that it is based on the memory address is a CPython implementation detail, that other Python implementations do not follow.

Comment: Given: `a=1` , `b=a` , `c=a`...  a,b,c all have the same `id()`.

Comment: Sure, they have the same id. What has that got to do with the OP question?

Comment: Just a note that references of a variable are all the same object.

Comment: @Jonathan Vanasco: The OP asked how to find the _object_ given its id(), not its name(s) -- which besides having more than one, it can also have none at all.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways and it's not difficult to do:

In O(n)

```
In [1]: def deref(id_):
   ....:     f = {id(x):x for x in gc.get_objects()}
   ....:     return f[id_]

In [2]: foo = [1,2,3]

In [3]: bar = id(foo)

In [4]: deref(bar)
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3]
```

A faster way on average, from the comments (thanks @Martijn Pieters):

```
def deref_fast(id_):
    return next(ob for ob in gc.get_objects() if id(ob) == id_)
```

The fastest solution is in the answer from @martineau, but does require exposing python internals.  The solutions above use standard python constructs.

Comment: You now created a reference to *every value in memory* ensuring that they'll not get garbage collected. You really want to use the [`weakref` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary) instead.

Comment: The OP asked from an academic standpoint, not a practical one.

Comment: But the OP won't be the only one looking at this; the idea of creating a mapping of id-to-object is nice, but it has certain consequences that you need to be aware of.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: True, but only until the all go away when the function returns and the local variable `f` no longer exists, right?

Comment: @martineau: good point; indeed, `f` only lives for the duration of the function call. At which point creating the dictionary is a waste of cycles because you may as well just scan through the list for an average cost of n/2 instead of a fixed cost of n (n being the number of objects in memory).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Perhaps, but it still might be more efficient as well as easier to develop and maintain than not being able to do it all.

Comment: @martineau: If the `dict()` was a `weakref.WeakValueDictionary()` and not just a local variable, then you can reuse it and then it's more efficient. By building it *each* and *every* time you call `deref()` you force it to loop through all objects. Doing `return next(ob for ob in gc.get_objects() if id(ob) == id_)` would only have to go through half the objects, on average. :-)

Comment: Not that you *can* reuse such a beast anyway, because next time you call, that same `id` could have been re-used already.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, reuse would be problematic -- for a moment I thought you were saying that the idea might be salvagable if it was a `WeakValueDictionary()` with a longer lifespan. Regardless, this answer as presented with a regular `dict`, _would_ work, albeit somewhat slowly.

Comment: Hi. Function `deref_fast` seems similar to, but better than, function `deref` on all aspects. I don't understand the sentence "but does require exposing python's internals". What is exposed by `deref_fast` that wasn't exposed by `deref` already? And if `deref_fast` is better than `deref` on all aspects, why keep `deref` at all in the answer?

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** Updated to Python 3.

Here's yet another answer adapted from a yet another [comment](https://web.archive.org/web/20070905071909/http://www.friday.com/bbum/2007/08/24/python-di/#comment-145316), this one by "Peter Fein", in the discussion @Hophat Abc referenced in his own answer to his own question.

Though not a general answer, but might still be useful in cases where you know something about the class of the objects whose ids you want to lookup — as opposed to them being the ids of *anything*.  I felt this might be a worthwhile technique even with that limitation (and sans the safety issues my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012814/355230) has). The basic idea is to make a class which keeps track of instances and subclasses of itself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import weakref

class MetaInstanceTracker(type):
    """ Metaclass for InstanceTracker. """

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dic):
        cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dic)
        cls.__instances__ = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
        return cls

class InstanceTracker(object, metaclass=MetaInstanceTracker):
    """ Base class that tracks instances of its subclasses using weakreferences. """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__instances__[id(self)]=self
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def find_instance(cls, obj_id):
        return cls.__instances__.get(obj_id, None)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    class MyClass(InstanceTracker):
        def __init__(self, name):
            super(MyClass, self).__init__()
            self.name = name
        def __repr__(self):
            return '{}({!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.name)

    obj1 = MyClass('Bob')
    obj2 = MyClass('Sue')

    print(MyClass.find_instance(id(obj1)))  # -> MyClass('Bob')
    print(MyClass.find_instance(id(obj2)))  # -> MyClass('Sue')
    print(MyClass.find_instance(42))        # -> None
```

Comment: I agree. Use [weakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) and set up a tracker. This is the right answer in my view.