# How to properly run memory-profiler in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a simple memory profiling in Jupyter Notebook (see Environment below) on macOS Catalina (10.15.2).  The code (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053380/what-does-del-do-exactly)) is as follows:

```
def mess_with_memory():
    huge_list = range(200)
    del huge_list
    print("Complete" )
```

This is how I call the profiler and the resulting profile (the 'importlib.reload' is not called the first time only for subsequent runs if I change the module):

[image]

What I expected to see was the 'Increment' column beginning with '0' and then having increasing then decreasing values line by line just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053380/what-does-del-do-exactly).  Instead the 'Increment' column starts at a certain value and subsequent values for each line are zero.  In the instance shown the value for range is very low but it doesn't matter if I increase it to a very much higher value, the result after a kernel restart is roughly the same.  If I don't restart the kernel and rerun repeatedly, the topmost value of the 'Increment' column increases.

I'm guessing this is because I'm running in Jupyter but the references I found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-up-jupyter-notebooks-20716cbe2025) indicate I should be able to do this.  Can anyone explain what might be happening or point me to where I can find that out?

Environment:

[image]