# Does using del with slicing creates a new object first and then deletes? Will it be in-place?

Tags: python, list, memory, slice, del

I want to know if slicing creates a copy of the list and if we use del over a slice. Then won't it create a copy, i.e. a new object from the list for a given slice first and then delete it?

So if a program is truly in-place then we cannot use slices.

```py
# suppose if I use something like this:
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
del a[5:]
```

So, won't this `del [a:]` create a copy of `a` in the given slice `a[5:]` and then delete it?

Is so, it won't be an in-place operation right as we are using slices here.

But

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
for i in range(5,len(a),-1):
    del a[i]
```

This operation is in-place since we are not using slices.

So this should be faster right? Because we don't have to go through the pain of creating a new slice and directly deleting the object.

But I checked and it is the opposite:

```py
%%timeit
a = [x for x in range(1000)]
del a[500:]
> 45.8 µs ± 3.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
a = [x for x in range(1000)]
for i in range(999,499,-1):
    del a[i]
> 92.9 µs ± 3.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Now, if we assume that `del a[500:]` creates a slice first and then deletes, then it's not truly in-place, and using a `for` loop for the same task is in-place?
But then why is the loop taking more time for the task?

Also, if in case, I assume that somehow they are both in-place and `del a[500:]` does not creates a slice copy of `a` at that index and `del` directly goes at the index 500 and recursively deletes the elements, then what is exactly `a[500:]` in this statement? Is it just to tell where should `del` delete from?

If so, then is it not a slice?

I referred to a few links such as the one below to find an answer to this, but I am not very clear from any of the explanations exclusively focusing on `in-place` operations.

[What does "del" do exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053380/what-does-del-do-exactly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to understand is that these are two different things:

```
del name
```

and

```
del container[index]
```

The first *deletes a name from the current namespace*. `del` does **not** work with arbitrary expressions, and it **does not delete objects**, it delete *names*:

```
>>> del [1,2,3]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot delete literal
>>> del list()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot delete function call
```

However,

```
del container[index]
```

Will invoke

```
container.__delitem__(index)
```

Which can do *whatever you want*, it can be in-place or not. Or not do anything...

On the other hand

```
container[index]
```

Invokes

```
container.__getitem__(index)
```

Which, again, can do whatever you want. It can return a copy, or if you want to implement it that way, it can work in-place.

Perhaps, this is enlightening:

```
>>> class Container:
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         print('Container.__getitem__ called with', item)
...     def __delitem__(self, item):
...         print('Container.__delitem__ called with', item)
...
>>> container = Container()
>>> container[:]
Container.__getitem__ called with slice(None, None, None)
>>> del container[:]
Container.__delitem__ called with slice(None, None, None)
>>> del container
```

Note, `del container` doesn't invoke either...

Answer (score 1):

> then what is exactly `a[500:]` in this statement? Is it just to tell where should `del` delete from?

Yes.

> Then won't it create a copy, i.e. a new object from the list for a given slice first and then delete it?

No copy is created. That's why `del` is a keyword, rather than a built-in function: it's special syntax that interprets the `a[5:]` part differently in context. (If it were a function, then `a[5:]` would have to be evaluated before the function could be called; and also the function couldn't possibly work, because it would be provided with a separate *value* rather than knowing which original object to operate on.)

> But I checked and they both take almost equal time:

```
for i in range(500,1000,-1):
```

Careful; this is an empty loop. You presumably intended `for i in range(1000, 500, -1)`, but that is not correct either - it should be `for i in range(999, 499, -1)` to get the matching behaviour. And now you understand why the slice syntax is supported for `del` :)

No idea about your timing results, anyway.