# Remove JSON element on loop in Python

Tags: python, json, element

I have this JSON

```
{"data": 
    [   
        {   
            "id": "11111", 
            "description": "Description 1", 
            "to_remove": "blah",
            "state": "Assigned"
        },
        {   
            "id": "2222", 
            "description": "Description 2",         
            "to_remove": "blah"
        },
        {   
            "id": "33333", 
            "description": "Description 3", 
            "to_remove": "blah",
            "state": "Assigned"
        }
]}
```

I need to remove all object where the "state" is not present and remove a single key (to_remove) in order to have this output:

```
{"data": 
    [   
        {   
            "id": "11111", 
            "description": "Description 1", 
            "state": "Assigned"
        },
        {   
            "id": "33333", 
            "description": "Description 3", 
            "state": "Assigned"
        }
]}
```

I tried with this code:

```
      json_data = json.loads(data)

      for element in json_data['data']:
          if 'state' in element:
             del element['to_remove']   
          else:
             del element
```

But the output is this:

```
{"data": 
    [   
        {   
            "id": "11111", 
            "description": "Description 1", 
            "state": "Assigned"
        },
        {   
            "id": "2222", 
            "description": "Description 2"          
            "to_remove": "blah",
        },
        {   
            "id": "33333", 
            "description": "Description 3", 
            "state": "Assigned"
        }
]}
```

I am able to remove a single key, but not all element.
The **del element** command not return error.
If I use a **del element['to_remove']** after **del element** I have error "name element not exist"

Answer (score 3):

`del element` just [unbinds the loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053380/what-does-del-do-exactly) `element`. That does not affect any other references to the same object. It does not remove it from the list. And if it did, you would be removing from a list while iterating it [which is also bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).

Instead, rebuild the list along the following lines:

```
data = []
for element in json_data['data']:
    if 'state' in element:
        del element['to_remove']   
        # more robust: element.pop('to_remove', None)
        data.append(element)
json_data['data'] = data
```