# Releasing memory after deleting object in Python?

Tags: python, memory

I am using a Python library to read a binary file into a Numpy array. To do this I first initialize an instance of a class from the library, give the path to my file as input, copy an attribute of that class to an Numpy array, and then delete the initialized instance to save memory.

The problem is that after this procedure I can see significant memory overhead after deleting the unnecessary objects. More precisely, the library I use is called `MDAnalysis`, the class I use from that library is `MDAnalysis.Universe`, the data I need from that class is `MDAnalysis.Universe.trajectory.velocity_array`. In detail, the memory use is as follows :

Initializing an object of type `Universe` with my data uses `1 Gb` of memory.

Copying `Universe.trajectory.velocity_array` to Numpy array uses `200 Mb` of memory.

Deleting the object of type `Universe` does not decrease the memory usage back to `200 Mb`, instead almost `1 Gb` is still used (monitored from JupyterLab).

So my question : Is deleting an instance of a specific class in Python using `del` always related to deletion of all variables and attributes of that object ? If not what is a better way to do this deletion ?

In reality I need to run a large number of parallel runs of that procedure in short time, and this because of this overhead the program has crashed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "del" do exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053380/what-does-del-do-exactly)

Comment: Either your library has a memory leak, holds onto the memory for other reasons or your Python script holds another reference to that object. It might be the jupyter notebook if you use it to inspect the objects

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would have a closer look at the related question and give more detailed answer.