# Warning seems to point to a different object address

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm using PySide and I get a warning when I try to set a spreadsheet to a certain widget:

```
09-18 14:48:54,107 WARNING  [D=0x7ff4a0074650:qt] Could not parse stylesheet of widget 0x1cbecc0
```

I've pinpointed the location of the problem and fixed it, but I was surprised to see that the address of the object calling `setStyleSheet()` is different:

```
<views.hierarchy.TreeView object at 0x7f3ab8139440>
```

Ideally, when I get warnings like the above I wish I could dereference it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011674/is-it-possible-to-dereference-variable-ids) and find out more about the cause.

My questions:

- Why are the two addresses different?
- Is there any way to get the address in the warning from the widget
  object?
- Is there any way to dereference the address in the warning directly?

Comment: Is one address the widget and one the style-sheet?

Comment: @mdurrant The "style-sheet" is just a string. And no, the address of the string would be a third, separate value. Besides, the warning claims "... of widget 0x1cbecc0"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the original warning is coming from Qt, and so the widget address given in the message is for the underlying C++ object. The other message you've shown is presumably from python, and therefore shows the address of the pyside wrapper object.

You can use the [shiboken module](https://pyside.github.io/docs/shiboken/shibokenmodule.html) (or the [sip module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html) for PyQt) to get information about the underlying C++ objects:

```
>>> import shiboken
>>> from PySide import QtGui
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
>>> w = QtGui.QWidget()
>>> repr(w)
'<PySide.QtGui.QWidget object at 0x7f7398c1d950>'
>>> w.setStyleSheet('{')
Could not parse stylesheet of widget 0x12e2fc0
>>> print(shiboken.dump(w))
C++ address....... PySide.QtGui.QWidget/0x12e2fc0 
hasOwnership...... 1
containsCppWrapper 1
validCppObject.... 1
wasCreatedByPython 1

>>> hex(shiboken.getCppPointer(w)[0])
>>> 0x12e2fc0
```

Combing this with the [gc module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#module-gc), it is possible to find the python wrapper object from the C++ address with a function like this:

```
import gc, shiboken

def wrapper_from_address(address):
    for item in gc.get_objects():
        try:
            if address == shiboken.getCppPointer(item)[0]:
                return item
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed; I knew of `gc.get_objects()` but couldn't link them to the C++ address.