# Understanding ctypes module's usage in this example code

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, ctypes

**Context:**
Some code I found which implements a XOR linked list. In XOR linked list, instead of each node having a next pointer, it has a `both` attribute which is the XOR of prev and next node.

```
import ctypes


# This is hacky. It's a data structure for C, not python.
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.both = 0


class XorLinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = self.tail = None
        self.__nodes = [] # This is to prevent garbage collection

    def add(self, node):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.both = id(node) ^ self.tail.both
            node.both = id(self.tail)
            self.tail = node

        # Without this line, Python thinks there is no way to reach nodes between
        # head and tail.
        self.__nodes.append(node)


    def get(self, index):
        prev_id = 0
        node = self.head
        for i in range(index):
            next_id = prev_id ^ node.both

            if next_id:
                prev_id = id(node)
                node = _get_obj(next_id)
            else:
                raise IndexError('Linked list index out of range')
        return node


def _get_obj(id):
    return ctypes.cast(id, ctypes.py_object).value
```

**Questions:**

1. Don't understand the need of `_get_obj()` function and what it is trying
   to do here?
2. How is `self.__nodes = []` useful? And how it implements
   garbage collection here?
3. I have no idea what the following code is doing:

   ```
   # Without this line, Python thinks there is no way to reach nodes between
   # head and tail.
   self.__nodes.append(node)`
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I can answer most of the sub-questions within your question.

1. the `_get_obj()` function is the inverse Python's own [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function (with the CPython interpreter anyway).
   There are other ways to do it. See for example the question [Is it possible to dereference variable id's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011674/is-it-possible-to-dereference-variable-ids/15012814).
2. & 3. The `self.__nodes.append(node)` adds the `Node` instance to a private list because adding it to the XOR linked-list doesn't create a reference to it as would likely happen in a more common normal implementation (the XOR trick eliminates the need for them). Without this, the Python garbage-collector might delete the `Node` instance while it was still part of the linked-list.