# how to get an function out of the storage slot

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, ram

Just a question out of interest in Python. How to get a function out of it storage slot?
Here I have an example:

```
>>> def func():
    pass

>>> func
<function func at 0x00000280B1883288>
```

So then `0x00000280B1883288` is the place where it is stored in the RAM memory, right?
But if I do this:

```
>>> eval('0x00000280B1883288')
2751757562504
>>> func
<function func at 0x00000280B1883288>
>>> 0x00000280B1883288
2751757562504
```

I only get an int back and if I try to call it I get the error that an int is not calleble. But is it possible to get a function out of its ram slot without calling func?

This is a question out of interest about how Python works, not that I don't know how to call a function, to make that clear.

Comment: No. Memory locations can not be accessed like that.

Comment: WIth cPython you may be able to use the `di()` function in my answer to the question [Is it possible to dereference variable id's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011674/is-it-possible-to-dereference-variable-ids) — I don't know if it would work for functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is CPython-specific, but it is possible to use `_ctypes` for this:

```
import _ctypes

def di(obj_id):
    """ Inverse of id() function. """
    return _ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(obj_id)

def func():
    return 42

func_id = id(func)
print(func)
print(hex(func_id))
print(di(func_id)())
```

This is adapted from [Is it possible to dereference variable id's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011674/is-it-possible-to-dereference-variable-ids)

P.S. I also briefly experimented with `_ctypes.call_function()` but didn't get very far.