# Can you hold pointers in a python list?

Tags: python, list, pointers, reference

For example

```
b = 4
c = []

c.append(b)

print(c)

b += 2

print(c)
```

I was hoping I would get

```
4
6
```

but I got

```
4
4
```

Any chance I could add the element as a pointer. And then if I reference that element with c[0] I'd be referencing the b?

Comment: No, not how Python variables work. `c` does not have any link to the variable `b`.

Comment: **Python doesn't have pointers**. However, pretty much everything has reference semantics. int objects are immutable though

Comment: @khelwood damn. thanks for the info. I guess I'll explore java or C++

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers either, and has the same semantics you are seeing here

Comment: I you suggest to check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011674/is-it-possible-to-dereference-variable-ids

Answer (score 0):

here `c` and `b` are different variables where `c` is list and `b` is int so if you add some on `b` it doesn't mean and `c` will be updated but if you add some number on `b` and append it again on `c`
there will be a change

```
b = 4
c = []

c.append(b)
print(c)
b += 2
c.append(c)
print(c)
```

and what you will get is

```
[4, 6]
```

and I think is clear that a `c` didn't change in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a class:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = int(number)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.number = self.number + other


b = Number(4)
c = []
c.append(b)
print(c)
b += 2
print(c)
```

You will get:

```
4
6
```

Comment: There is https://pypi.org/project/mutableint/ which does essentially this, except that you can also use it in arithmetic etc.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this below link to understand how the reference works in python:
[How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

So, in short,
python objects i.e. `booleans`, `integers`, `floats`, `strings`, and `tuples` are **immutable**, which means that after you create the object and assign some value to it, you can't modify that value.

Hence, when you do `b += 2`, here, `b` will point to a new memory reference.

**Proof:**

```
>>> b=10
>>> id(b)
1734146112
>>> b+=2
>>> id(b)
1734146144
>>>
```

However, as @[yoav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11281299/yoav) mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62735032/9471752),

you can also do this by tweaking the default behaviour of `Number` class but beware; you should use it very carefully as you might not need this behaviour for every class.