# Complement of python's id() function?

Tags: python, cpython

Python's `id()` returns the identity of an object as an integer.

Is there a Python function that does the compliment of that? That is, a function `X()` such that:

```
class ABC(object): pass
a = ABC()
b = X(id(a))
assert b is a
```

Comment: This might help: [Is it possible to dereference variable id's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011674/is-it-possible-to-dereference-variable-ids)

Comment: If all you have is the `id` of an object, rather than an actual reference to it - the object could very well have been garbage-collected, so if your hypothetical `X()` function returned anything at all, there would be no guarantee that it was the original object.