# List element Pointer in Python

Tags: python

My question comes from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905527/python-get-a-pointer-to-a-list-element), while I would like to create a pointer(-like thing) for an list element. The element is a primitive value (string) so I have to create a FooWrapper class as that page says.

I know that by setting `__repr__` one can directly access this value.

```
class FooWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
         return repr(self.value)


>>> bar=FooWrapper('ABC')
>>> bar
'ABC'
>>> bar=FooWrapper(3)
>>> bar
3
```

Now I can use it as an reference of string:

```
>>> L=[3,5,6,9]
>>> L[1]=FooWrapper('ABC')
>>> L
[3,'ABC',6,9]
>>> this=L[1]
>>> this.value='BCD'
>>> print(L)
[3,'BCD',6,9]
```

So now I have a pointer-like `this` for the list element `L[1]`.

However it is still inconvenient since I must use `this.value='BCD'` to change its value. While there exists a `__repr__` method to make `this` directly return `this.value`, is there any similar method to make `this='BCD'` to do `this.value='BCD'` ? I know this changes the rule of binding.. but anyway, is it possible?

I would also appreciate if there is a better solution for a list element pointer.

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: `__repr__` isn't at all doing what you claim. Defining it does *not* make `this` return `this.value`; it simply makes it print that value in the console. `this == 3` would always return False, for example, and `this * 5` would give a TypeError.

Comment: Umm,  I agree with this. While eventually I would print them out, or write to a file etc, so it could work though.

Comment: I'll use `[str(x) for x in this]` eventually.

Comment: You could use an int pointing to the list index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but you could do something like:

```
class FooWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
         return 'FooWrapper(' + repr(self.value) + ')'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    def __call__(self,value):
        self.value = value
```

Here I got rid of your idea of using `__repr__` to hide `FooWrapper` since I think it a bad idea to hide from the programmer what is happening at the REPL. Instead -- I used `__str__` so that when you *print* the object you will print the wrapped value. The `__call__` functions as a default method, which doesn't change the meaning of `=` but is sort of what you want:

```
>>> vals = [1,2,3]
>>> vals[1] = FooWrapper("Bob")
>>> vals
[1, FooWrapper('Bob'), 3]
>>> for x in vals: print(x)

1
Bob
3
>>> this = vals[1]
>>> this(10)
>>> vals
[1, FooWrapper(10), 3]
```

However, I think it misleading to refer to `this` as a pointer. It is just a wrapper object, and is almost certain to make dealing with the wrapped object inconvenient.

On Edit: The following is more of a *pointer* to a list. It allows you to create something like a pointer object with `__call__` used to dereference the pointer (when no argument is passed to it) or to mutate the list (when a value is passed to `__call__`). It also implements a form of `p++` called (`pp`) with wrap-around (though the wrap-around part could of course be dropped):

```
class ListPointer(object):
    def __init__(self, myList,i=0):
         self.myList = myList
         self.i = i % len(self.myList)

    def __repr__(self):
         return 'ListPointer(' + repr(self.myList) + ',' + str(self.i) + ')'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.myList[self.i])

    def __call__(self,*value):
        if len(value) == 0:
            return self.myList[self.i]
        else:
            self.myList[self.i] = value[0]

    def pp(self):
        self.i = (self.i + 1) % len(self.myList)
```

Used like this:

```
>>> vals = ['a','b','c']
>>> this = ListPointer(vals)
>>> this()
'a'
>>> this('d')
>>> vals
['d', 'b', 'c']
>>> this.pp()
>>> this()
'b'
>>> print(this)
b
```

I think that this is a more transparent way of getting something which acts like a list pointer. It doesn't require the thing pointed to to be wrapped in anything.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps `__call__` is also convenient to use.

Comment: @RuixingWang Thanks. Perhaps you will find the new class definition I just added more useful.

Comment: Thank you again for the edit while I got a good idea based on yours. (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

The `__repr__` method can get a string however it wants to.  Let's say it says `return repr(self.value) + 'here'`.  If you say `this = '4here'`, what should be affected?  Should `self.value` be assigned to `4` or `4here`?  What if `this` had another attribute called `key` and `__repr__` did `return repr(self.key) + repr(self.value)`?  When you did `this = '4here'`, would it assign `self.key` to the whole string, assign `self.value` to the whole string, or assign `self.key` to `4` and `self.value` to `here`?  What if the string is completely made up by the method?  If it says `return 'here'`, what should `this = '4here'` do?

In short, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Self-Answer based on John Coleman's idea:

```
class ListPointer(object):
    def __init__(self,list,index):
          self.value=list[index]
          list[index]=self
    def __repr__(self):
          return self.value
    def __call__(self,value):
          self.value=value

>>> foo=[2,3,4,5]
>>> this=ListPointer(foo,2)
>>> this
4
>>> foo
[2,3,4,5]
>>> this('ABC')
>>> foo
[2,3,'ABC',5]
>>> type(foo(2))
<class '__main__.ListPointer'>
```

`ListPointer` object accepts a list and an index, stores the `list[index]` in `self.value` and then substitutes the list element with `self`. Similarly a `pp` method can also be achieved, while the former element should be restored and the next element be substituted with `self` object. By directly referring `foo[2]` one also gets this object, which is what I want. (Perhaps this should be called as a  reference rather than a pointer..)