# Referencing List Items through Variables

Tags: python

My original thought process was that I could reference an item in a list easier by saving it in a variable.

Let's say I've created a list:

```
list = [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0]
```

Can I store each item in a variable?

```
list1 = list[0]

list2 = list[1]

list3 = list[2]

list4 = list[3]
```

Then change that item using the variable:

```
list1 =+ 1
```

But here the original list remains the same:

```
print(list)
```

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

So it would appear the variable takes the value from the list, and I'm only changing the variable not the original list.

```
print(list1)
```

> 1

Is there a way to store list items in variables but have it so I'm actually performing operations on the items in the list, not 'copies' of the item?

Comment: Why not just change the list using the index? list[0] += 1

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Why not just do `list[index] += 1`?

Comment: Two immediate things; don't use `list` as a name, and `list1 =+ 1` probably isn't what you wanted, maybe `+=`

Comment: Trying to work around the pythonic way of doing operations is not recommendable. Besides, why would you want so many variables? Big no no!

Comment: Check this awnser.. This has been already asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905527/python-get-a-pointer-to-a-list-element

Answer (score 0):

Not without a lot of hacking together custom classes with overidden `__dict__` values. Python assignments for primitives are pass-by-value which means that any call to `x=y` will always make a copy of `y` and any changes to `x` will not affect `y`.