# Get an object from its address

Tags: python

I want to get the instance of an class object. I have its address and the name of the object. How can it be possible to create the instance of the object or how can I retrieve the same object?

The class is defined in one python module and i want it to be used in another python module.

Can I use object id to access the object of the class.?

---

My actual problem is that I have a Python module in which a class had been defined (`class Myclass`). I am reusing the module in my new code. I want the object of `Myclass`, which is defined in the old module, to be accessed in my new file.

Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this? I don't have right to access the module source code where the class has been defined. I can manage to get the class name with the garbage collector.

Comment: The object id does not necessarily have anything to do with the internal address where the object lives in memory. So no, it’s not possible to get a Python object from the id, or from any “address” (whereever you get that from). Instead, you should just make a dictionary somewhere, where you store your objects if you want to look them up later.

Comment: If you have the address of an object (by which I assume you mean a reference to it?) then that's all you need to talk to the object.

Comment: Hello Joe,  I don't have the reference of the object. I just had the physical memory address (0X14356700). And one more thing My original class is defined in the file where i had no access to the source. I just had the binary of it to access or to reuse the code.

Comment: @mkreddy Have you read: [Python: Get object by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396668/python-get-object-by-id)?

Comment: The `id()` of an object and the address of it in memory are not the same thing.  They happen to be in CPython, but that is an implementation detail.

Comment: Tip: it looks like you've fallen into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Instead of asking about your actual problem, you came up with a possible solution and then asked about how to get that to work.  We've all made this mistake from time to time, which is why it's always a good idea to give the "actual problem" too.  Often someone else can point out a much better approach which you'd never have heard of if you only asked a very narrow question.

Answer (score 2):

By the `id` you can't. By name:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.v = val
myInst = A(3)
print eval("myInst").v
>>> 3
```

Comment: That only works if the variable holding a reference to that object is actually in scope.

Answer (score 2):

`id` is only defined as a number *unique to the element among currently existing elements. Some Python implementations (in fact, all main ones but CPython) do not return the memory address.

```
%~> pypy
Python 2.7.3 (480845e6b1dd219d0944e30f62b01da378437c6c, Aug 08 2013, 17:02:19)
[PyPy 2.1.0 with GCC 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``arguably, everything is a niche''
>>>> a = 1
>>>> b = 2
>>>> c = 3
>>>> id(a)
9L
>>>> id(b)
17L
>>>> id(c)
25L
```

So you have to guarantee that it *is* the memory address. Furthermore, because of this Python provides no `id → object` mapping, especially as the object that an `id` maps to can be changed if the original is deleted.

You have to ask why you're holding the `id`. If it's for space reasons, bear in mind that containers actually hold *references* to items, so `[a, a, a, a, a]` actually takes less space than `[id(a), id(a), id(a), id(a), id(a)]; a`.

You can consider also making a `dict` of `{id: val}` for all the relevant items and storing that. This will keep `val` alive, so you can use [`weakref`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html)s to allow the `val`s to be garbage collected. Remember, [use `weakref` if you want a `weakref`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html).

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. My actual problem is " I have a python module in which a class had been defined "Class Myclass". I am reusing the module in my new code. I want the object of Myclass which is defined in the old module have to be accessed in my new file. Can any one suggest me a way to achieve this. I don't have right to access the module where the class has defined. I can mange to get the class name with garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

> My actual problem is " I have a python module in which a class had been defined "Class Myclass". I am reusing the module in my new code. I want the object of Myclass which is defined in the old module have to be accessed in my new file. Can any one suggest me a way to achieve this. I don't have right to access the module where the class has defined. I can mange to get the class name with garbage collector.

If you are *reusing* the module, then you have access to that module.

For example if said module creates the object like this:

```
class MyClass:
    pass

myobj = MyClass()
```

Then you can import that reference too when you import the module:

```
from othermodule import MyClass, myobj
```

Comment: Thank you I will try with this and will get back to you.