# Python inverse function of id(...) built-in function

Tags: python, uuid, built-in

Is there a reverse or inverse of the `id` built-in function? I was thinking of using it to encode and decode string without taking too much time or having a lot of overhead like the `PyCrypto` library. The need for me is quite simple so I don't want to use `PyCrypto` for a simple encode and decode.

Something like:

```
>>> id("foobar")
4330174256
>>> reverse_id(4330174256) # some function like this to reverse.
"foobar"
```

Comment: [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) might fit your needs better...

Comment: `id` is not a string encoding function. It returns a unique ID for the passed object, which may change between runs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I do not wanna to steal the credits from the [man who answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702647/2456721)

```
This can be done easily by ctypes:

import ctypes
a = "hello world"
print ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value
output:

hello world
```

Comment: Ah, cool! I guess I didn't scroll far enough down the page. I still think `base64` is much more appropriate for what the OP is trying to do here, though.

Comment: @dano I think so too but he answered **Is there a reverse or inverse of the id built-in function?**

Comment: Oh, for sure (which is why I upvoted you). But sometimes the OP thinks they needs an answer for one question, when they really need a different answer to a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) module would fit your needs here, rather than trying to use `id`:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode("foobar")
'Zm9vYmFy'
>>> base64.b64decode('Zm9vYmFy')
'foobar'
```

The answer to your literal question (can I look up an object by its id?) is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396668/python-get-object-by-id). <strike>The short answer is no, you can't.</strike>  **Edit:** Victor Castillo Torres ponits out that [this actually is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702647/2073595) if you're using CPython, via the `ctypes` module.