# Is it possible to make a variable an object of a class by changing its type?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Assume that we have a `test()`class defined as below :

```
>>> class test():
    pass
```

Normally when I run the below code I make `Obj` as an object of my `test()` class :

```
>>> obj=test()
>>> 
>>> obj
<__main__.test object at 0x00000000031B2390>
>>> type(obj)
<class '__main__.test'>
>>>
```

As you see above `obj` has two features. It has a value and a type.

In the below, I assign `Obj` value as a string to another variable called `var1` :

```
>>> var1='<__main__.test object at 0x00000000031B2390>'
>>> 
>>> type(var1)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

As you see above , `obj1` and `var1` are equal in value, but are different in type. And again, as you know we can change type of an object to string using `str()` function as below :

```
>>> Obj=str(Obj)
>>> Obj
'<__main__.test object at 0x00000000031B2390>'
>>>
```

Now, I want to know if is there any way to reverse above function? I mean, Is there any way to make a string-type variable as a object?

I mean is there any way to make `Var1` equal to `Obj`?

In the other word, assume that I know `<__main__.test object at 0x00000000031B2390>` is the value of an object of a class. But I don't know neither the name of the object nor the name of the class. Now I want to create another object of that class. Is there any way?

Comment: *"`obj1` and `var1` are equal in value"* - what?! And that isn't the *"value"* of `obj`, just the default `__repr__` (representation) of the object. You seem to have fundamentally misunderstood what is going on here.

Comment: Do you want to create an object from just a class name or do you want some kind of serialisation?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Isn't the value of both equal to `<__main__.test object at 0x00000000031B2390>` ?

Comment: No.  A test object is not at all the same thing as the string you see when you ask for its value.  That's just a way of representing the object in a human-readable way.  The object is actually a blob of memory (the long number is the location in memory where it's stored), and you cannot get from a string back to the actual object.  It's like trying to recreate a house by picking up the numbers on the mailbox and putting them in another lot.

Comment: @ti4programing what do you mean by *"value"*?

Comment: @tttthomasssss Assume that I know `<__main__.test object at 0x00000000031B2390>` is the value of an object of a class. But I don't know neither the name of that object nor the name of the class. Now I want to create another object of that class. Is there any way?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Value : I mean the statement that is returned when I type its name and press enter!

Comment: You know a name of the class: `__main__.test`. However, you don't know any of the details necessary to create a duplicate instance (Python does not let you work with arbitrary blobs of memory; the address is simply the value used by the interpreter as a unique integer identifier, nothing more.)

Comment: @ti4programing that's just the *representation* - except for simple types like `int` it doesn't make sense to call that a "value".

Comment: This entire conversation has already happened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396668/python-get-object-by-id), and the [short answer is no, you can't easily get an object from its id](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1396696/786020). But it does have a brute force way to do it, which won't work with your code since `Obj=str(Obj)` will probably cause `Obj` to be cleaned up, as that removes the last reference of it in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the *representation* of an object (`obj.__repr__()`, or [`repr(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr)) with its *value* (which doesn't necessarily have a sensible meaning for all types of object *). Here is an example of an object with a misleading representation:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a
1
>>> class FakeInt(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "1"


>>> b = FakeInt()
>>> b
1
>>> a == b
False
>>> a + b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    a + b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'FakeInt'
```

`a` *looks like* `b`, but isn't equal to it and cannot be used in the same way.

It is conventional to implement `__repr__` and `__eq__` instance methods such that `eval(repr(obj)) == obj`. This allows you to create new objects that are equal to the existing ones, for example:

```
>>> class SillyString(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.string = s
    def __repr__(self):
        return "SillyString({0.string!r})".format(self)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.string == other.string


>>> s = SillyString("foo")
>>> repr(s)
"SillyString('foo')"
>>> eval(repr(s)) == s
True # equal to s
>>> eval(repr(s)) is s 
False # but not identical to s, i.e. a separate object
```

However this seems pointless for your `test` objects, because they don't have attributes or methods to copy anyway.

---

* For example, here is an object definition:

```
def some_obj(object):

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
```

What should its *"value"* be? `foo`? `bar`? Some combination of the two?

Answer (score 1):

There are a fair few misconceptions here.

First, it is untrue to say that a variable has two things, a value and a type. It has one thing only: a value. That value has a type. Variables in Python do not have types, they are simply names pointing at things.

Secondly, assigning a string that looks like the repr of an object does not somehow make the value equal to the object. A string is just a string.

Comment: OK. Is there any way to transfer an string to an object?

Comment: No. You are missing the point that the string returned by `obj.__repr__` is in no way sufficient to recreate a copy of that object.

Comment: @chepner What I need to recreate an object without using `var1=test()` or `var1=obj`? Is it possible any way?

Comment: @ti4programing please (again) provide a **less abstract example**. Given that a `test` instance has no attributes or behaviour, what's the point of *"recreating"* it? And why do you need to do this; why do you only have the string, and where did it come from?