# Converting a memory address to a function object

Tags: python

A light in Maya has an attribute `Use Color Temperature`, which is a checkbox, when I toggle it, a function is called inside Maya to actually do the work behind the scene. Unfortunately the function address `<function callback at 0x0000000051CD7DD8>` is printed out instead of it's name. I don't know which function is executed when clicking the checkbox. Is there any way of converting this address to python function object or can I print the actual name of the function using this memory address?

Comment: This probably means a function called `callback` is called. I'd look for `def callback(...):`

Comment: `callback` is the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like pure evil and to be honest, I think you can/should use `callback` instead.  But for reference, apparently you can use the garbage collection module `gc` to get the object from that `id`.

Found on this [SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396690/3155195) (you really can find anything on SO...):

```
import gc

def objects_by_id(id_):
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if id(obj) == id_:
            return obj
    raise Exception("No found")
```

I believe you need to coerce that number into an `int` representation because `id(obj)` returns an `int` rather than `hex`.

NB this may have some weird race conditions with object ids potentially being recycled after an object is deleted.

Comment: Python automatically converts hex to int. Try passing the hex to `objects_by_id`

Answer (score 3):

This means a function named `callback` is called.

I'd look for `def callback(...):` in the corresponding code file and see what it does.

To re-produce your output all that's needed is a function with the name `callback`:

```
>>> def callback():
...     print "My name is Reut Sharabani"
... 
>>> cb = callback
>>> cb
<function callback at 0x7f182f3ca6e0>
```

If you want to programmatically get a function's name:

```
>>> cb.__name__
'callback'
```

If you want to know more about it you can even disassemble it using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) and it's [code object](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/code.html):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(cb.__code__)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('My name is Reut Sharabani')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```