# Can somebody explain why the Python Interpreter doesn't get confused in this instance of using decorators?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am trying to understand decorators from this [link](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/).

I have two simple files a.py and b.py

a.py has the following code:

```
def f1(input_func):
    def inner_func():
        input_func()
        input_func()
    return inner_func
```

b.py has the following code:

```
import a
def saying():
    print('Hello')
saying = a.f1(saying)
saying()
```

My question is, for the aforementioned instance how does the interpreter know that I am calling the `saying` object that points to `a.f1(saying)` and not the object that points to the definition of saying (`print('Hello')`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** You are overwriting the variable name, so the interpreter will simply use the latest definition. Once you run `saying = a.f1(saying)`, there is no longer any way to directly call your original `saying` unless you have saved it in another variable.

If you want a longer explanation...

### Garbage Collection

Normally when you overwrite variables like this, the old value / place in memory is completely erased by the garbage collector. However, in your case the original `saying` is saved in memory since it is used when calling `f1(saying)`. You just can't access it, again unless you have saved it in another variable before reassigning it.

Let's look at the memory references using the `id` function to get a better idea of what's going on.

If you run this code:

```
def f1(input_func):
    def inner_func():
        input_func()
        input_func()
    return inner_func

def saying():
    print('Hello')

print("saying address:", hex(id(saying)))
saying()
print("---")

saying = f1(saying)
print("new saying address = f1(saying):", hex(id(saying)))
saying()
```

You'll get something like this:

```
saying address: 0x7fa960295820
Hello
---
new saying address = f1(saying): 0x7fa9602958b0
Hello
Hello
```

You can see that the two functions are saved in different memory addresses, and `saying` now points to the new address.

If we save the first address ahead of time, we can use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777050/converting-a-memory-address-to-a-function-object) to recover the original function. You would never want to do this in practice (it is infinitely easier to simply save the original `saying` in a different variable), but for instructional purposes only:

```
import gc

# ... define f1 and saying as before

def object_by_id(id_):
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if id(obj) == id_:
            return obj
    raise Exception("Not found")

origId = id(saying)
print("saying address:", hex(origId))
saying()
print("---")

saying = f1(saying)
print("new saying address = f1(saying):", hex(id(saying)))
saying()
print("---")

saying = object_by_id(origId)
print("saying address after recovery: ", hex(id(saying)))
if id(saying) == origId:
  print( "Matches original!")
saying()
```

Output:

```
saying address: 0x7f0c2db4a820
Hello
---
new saying address = f1(saying): 0x7f0c2db4a8b0
Hello
Hello
---
saying address after recovery:  0x7f0c2db4a820
Matches original!
Hello
```

So you can see that the original function has indeed been recovered. Again, this only works because the new value of `saying = f1(saying)` contains in its definition a call to the original function.

However, what happens if the call to `f1` doesn't include `saying`, but instead calls another function? Then the original `saying` is lost permanently. You can see this by adding this snippet to the end of the previous code:

```
def otherFunc():
  print(1)

saying = f1(otherFunc)
print("new saying address = f1(otherFunc):", hex(id(saying)))
saying()
print("---")

saying = object_by_id(origId) # Exception: Not found
```

No variables reference the original `saying` any longer, so the garbage collector removes it and it is no longer recoverable at all.

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/YawningRadiantRam#main.py)

Comment: Thank you. That was incredibly detailed and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you make the assignment

```
saying = a.f1(saying)
```

from this point on `saying` points what was evaluated by `a.f1(saying)`, which in this case is the decorated `saying` function.

If you were to swap the last two lines of py.b then `saying()` would still call the undecorated `saying` function.