# Check if an object id exists in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, cpython

Simple: I have an Python object id, and I want to check if there is an object with that id.

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702647), you can get an existing object by id with

```
import ctypes
a = 10
object_id = id(a)
ctypes.cast(object_id, ctypes.py_object).value
```

But it hangs when called with a arbitrary `object_id`, so that's an impractical solution.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1396690/2683246)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you'd need an exhaustive enumeration of all Python objects. Otherwise, it's impossible to tell the difference between an object and a memory region that just happens to look like an object.

Unfortunately, there isn't such an exhaustive list. The closest thing is probably `gc.get_objects()`, which returns a list of all objects tracked by the garbage collector (excluding the list itself). You could search that for an object matching your ID, but things like `x = 1; print x in gc.get_objects()` won't find the object.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. It's an object that isn't in gc.get_objects that I'm interested in. Why isn't it being tracked!? Thanks.

Comment: @jmilloy: `1` is untracked because it can't possibly participate in a reference cycle. Whatever object you're trying to find, either it's untracked because Python knows it can't be in a reference cycle, or it's already been collected.

Comment: The object I'm interested in is a numpy array that's an attribute of a class. When the attribute is assigned to a new object, it seems that the old object never goes away.

Comment: @jmilloy: Why are you trying to do this, anyway? Wouldn't a weakref or an actual reference be more useful than the ID?

Comment: I still don't entirely understand when and why this object is getting collected, or the effect that gc.collect is having on the total memory usage of the process (none). But in the process I got curious. I don't actually need an answer to the question to solve the issue.

Comment: @jmilloy, in CPython an object is deallocated when its reference count goes to 0. You can check the reference count via `sys.getrefcount(obj) - 1` (minus 1 for the call stack reference). How this affects available memory is a complex subject. It depends on the size of the object, the operating system, the allocator configuration (e.g. glibc `mallopt` options `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD` and `M_TRIM_THRESHOLD`), and a high-water mark effect resulting from the fact that CPython objects never move in memory, which can prevent the heap from shrinking.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks, that's really helpful. I was too fixated on the gc module.