# Access value in memory address

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory

I want to access a value in memory address.

Code1:

```
value = 10
print(id(value))

>> 10894368
```

Code2 (I don't know how):

```
accessValue(10894368)

>> 10
```

Comment: yep, this is a duplicate, sorry

Comment: Use C, not Python.

Comment: This is a duplicate of:
[Python: Get object by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396668/python-get-object-by-id)

Comment: i want to do in python