# What's the recommended "pythonic way" for unpacking a byte encoded message with arbitrary bit length fields?

Tags: python, bytebuffer, unpack

Suppose I have a byte-packed message with the following schema:

```
Message Name: Ball
    Field #1: 
        Name: Color
        Type: unsigned int
        Start Bit: 0
        Bit Length: 4
    Field #2: 
        Name: Radius
        Type: single
        Start Bit: 4
        Bit Length: 32
    Field #3: 
        Name: New
        Type: bool
        Start Bit: 36
        Bit Length: 1
```

What is the recommended pythonic way to convert the byte sequence into a python variables? Would the "struct" module work well for unpacking byte arrays that have arbitrary bit length fields?

Comment: I suspect this question will end up closed for one reason or another, but in the interest of helping anyway, [`construct`](http://construct.readthedocs.io) would probably be better-suited than `struct`.

Comment: Hmm, check out [this](http://varx.org/wordpress/2016/02/03/bit-fields-in-python/).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I think that is a perfect example. I was very familiar with how to do this in C, but I was curious the proper python method. I like the references in that article for using native python libraries.

Comment: @jwodder: Thank you. I'll check that out, but was hoping for a native python approach.

Comment: @Pat yeah, if you want to do something like you would do it in C, generally `ctypes` and `struct` with maybe `array` modules is what you need to look at.

Comment: @Pat this even lets you do all sorts of [unsafe, dark magic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15702647/5014455) that you might not think is possible in Python. Although, I wouldn't recommend the above.

Comment: Shouldn't the title of your question be about the unpacking a **bit** encoded message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What is the recommended pythonic way to convert the byte sequence into a python variables?*

What you want is to read [this python doc page about `struct` and `bytearray`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

It will show you how to `pack` and `unpack` data using format.

> *Would the "struct" module work well for unpacking byte arrays that have arbitrary bit length fields?*

It will show you how to `pack` and `unpack` data using format.

Yup, as follows:

```
import struct
color, radius, new = struct.unpack("If?", incoming_bytes)
```

Check the [format characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) to define the format string and you're done.

You could use more bloated libraries like `construct`, but TBH, this format is super simple and if you `unpack` early and `pack` late, you're free to organize your data as you want in your code.

e.g.:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, color, radius, new):
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        self.new = new

Ball(*unpack("If?", incoming_bytes))
```