# how to access variable address and delete it using python

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to delete the memory address of a variable in python?
For example, 
I was implementing an code like

`var = 23
address = hex(id(var))
print (var+":"+address)
del address
print (var+":"+address)`
If I want to remove address of the variable var then show an error message like 
Name Error: name 'address' is not defined
Is there any way to delete the variable address or modify the value of the variable using address variable?

Comment: Why? Perhaps a `dict` rather than variables would suit your use case here.

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing del adress you're not removing the adress of the variable, you're only clearing the "adress" variable which contains a string that represents the hexadecimal of the adress, that's why you're getting an "not defined" error.

[You can access the value by using the ctypes module :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396668/get-object-by-id/15702647#15702647)

```
ctypes.cast(id(var), ctypes.py_object).value
```

But I don't know if it's possible to modify the variable, but like [Chaos said :](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396696) 
Basically, if you're trying to do this, you probably need to do something differently.