# Passing object references in a queue across processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have several `multiprocessing.Process`es and would like them to consume (queue `get()`) callable non-picklable objects and call them. These were created before the `fork()`, so they shouldn't need pickling.

Using `multiprocessing.Queue` doesn't work as it tries to pickle everything:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

# create non-global callable to make it unpicklable
def make_callable():
    def foo():
        print("running foo")
    return foo

def bar():
    print("running bar")

def runall(q):
    while True:
        c = q.get()
        if c is None:
            break
        c()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    call = make_callable()
    p = mp.Process(target=runall, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    q.put(bar)
    q.put(call)
    q.put(None)
    p.join()
```

```
running bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 236, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'make_callable.<locals>.foo'
```

An implementation equivalent would be putting all objects into a global (or passed) list and passing just indexes, which works:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

# create non-global callable to make it unpicklable
def make_callable():
    def foo():
        print("running foo")
    return foo

def bar():
    print("running bar")

def runall(q, everything):
    while True:
        c = q.get()
        if c is None:
            break
        everything[c]()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    call = make_callable()
    everything = [bar, call]
    p = mp.Process(target=runall, args=(q,everything))
    p.start()
    q.put(0)
    q.put(1)
    q.put(None)
    p.join()
```

```
running bar
running foo
```

The problem is that while I know that none of the callables passed will be garbage collected (and thus their addresses will stay valid), I do not have the full list beforehand.

I also know I could probably use `multiprocessing.Manager` and its `Queue` implementation using a `Proxy` object, but this seems like a lot of overhead, especially as in the real implementation I would be passing other picklable data as well.

Is there a way to pickle and pass only the address reference to an object, shared across multiple processes?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any good workaround for this issue? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

True that Process' target objects must be pickable.

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully
>   qualified” name reference, not by value.This means that only the
>   function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the
>   function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its
>   function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be
>   importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain
>   the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.

Picklable functions and classes must be defined in the top level of a module.

So in your case you need to proceed with passing top-level callables but applying additional checks/workarounds in the crucial `runall` function:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

# create non-global callable to make it unpicklable
def make_callable():
    def foo():
        print("running foo")
    return foo

def bar():
    print("running bar")

def runall(q):
    while True:
        c = q.get()
        if c is None:
            break

        res = c()
        if callable(res): res()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=runall, args=(q,))
    p.start()

    q.put(bar)
    q.put(make_callable)
    q.put(None)

    p.join()
    q.close()
```

The output:

```
running bar
running foo
```

Comment: Yes, that's the obvious solution to the obviously trivial example. However, in my case, I don't know and cannot guarantee that the callables my library gets are top-level and there's not a good reason to mandate picklability and limit the user.

Comment: @JiříJ, The rule is clear - the passed should be pickable. And it's not a good reason if a user can pass "anything" to "anywhere".

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of thinking and searching, I believe I have the answer I was looking for, mostly from: [Get object by id()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396668/get-object-by-id).

I could pass an `id()` of the callable and then translate it back in the spawned process:

```py
import ctypes
a = "hello world"
print ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value
```

Or use the `gc` module and, as long as I keep a reference to the object alive, that should work too:

```py
import gc

def objects_by_id(id_):
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if id(obj) == id_:
            return obj
    raise Exception("No found")
```

However neither of these are very clean and, in the end, it may be worth imposing a limitation of having all the callables first and just passing indexes.